# Wide range power supply accepting both AC and DC from 12 to 240V

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

What is the "common" way to build such a source? I have seen time relay CRM-93H that can be powered by "AC/DC 12-240V (AC50-60Hz)". I failed to find any IC or transformer in it, but it is build on a high voltage MOSFET IRFU420B. Another example Voltage and Frequency Relay UFR1001E the can be powered with "AC/DC 24-270 V, 0/40...70 Hz" but with power supply build on TNY280GN. I have not seen power supplies like this before. May be there is some good book or website where can I find examples of simple, low power (something about 200-300 mA) but nearly universal power supply? Output voltage may be from 3.3 to 24 V.

Comment: I would think you need to directly take the input voltage through a rectifier and go from there. You have not specified output voltage so no one can say anything else about the about the rest of your power supply.

Comment: One technique if the dc range is limited but AC can go to 240V is to use a circuit the detects the voltage and turns off the mosfet. With AC this ends up chopping the waveform so this gets filtered with a capacitor then a linear or buck regulator.

Comment: Output voltage can be from 3.3 to 24 V.

Comment: Here's a [datasheet](https://www.rayleigh.com/media/uploads/CRM-91H_93H_9S_datasheet_09-01-15.pdf). Please remember to link the datasheet in your question whenever asking about a specific part.

Comment: You appear to be extrapolating operational input ranges of relays with universal power supplies.  The relay will operate at one input voltage (in usage it will not change), while the power supply has to deal with the source input.  Two different issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a peak voltage range >30:1 input might be possible for low power and low DC output in buck, hysteretic or forward converters such as to drive a relay coil in your examples.

The best design guides are supplied by the OEM's of the components. e.g. TI, ADI, Magnetics, and Capacitor companies.

Generally, DC-DC power converters are optimized for a 2:1 range input due to cost reductions and tradeoffs. Adding more dynamic input range can add complexity.

Suggestion:
TI Power Design and choose AC input and DC output range.  https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator/select

With a free login, examine results for suitability to your specs.